# How do i use regex to parse text between two any strings?

Tags: c#, .net

For example i have this line i want to parse some text from:

New> Android > Android Application

And this is the Regex i'm trying to use:

```
private List<string> ExtractFromString(string s, string startTag, string endTag)
        {
            var names = new List<string>();

            Regex r1 = new Regex(@"One([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)Three");

            return names;
        }
```

But instead One i need it to use the startTag and instead Three to use endTag.
And in the example line the startTag could be once the first Android word but in other cases it can be the second Android word and maybe there might be cases that there are more same words in the startTag and endTag the idea is also to know to parse the text between the words that in the startTag and endTag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to build your regex dynamically like this:

```
Regex r1 = new Regex(startTag + @"([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)" + endTag);
```

As long as there are no special characters in the start or end tag it will be good. You also have to make sure that the tags are unique and don't show up anywhere between the tags or things get more complicated depending on how you want to handle that.

Comment: What i get as result for example is: And([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)App but i want to get as string the text between the two tags. What i did is: names.Add(r1.ToString());

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookahead and a lookbehind:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?=" + startTag + ")[A-Za-z0-9\-]+(?<=" + endTag + ")");
```